# Media Resize plugin not working on article images

Tags: articles, images, media-manager

I have a Joomla 4 site and have enabled the 'Media Action - Resize' plugin, I have set the max width and max height in the plugin params to be 500

When I upload an image via Content > Media, it resizes the image with no problems.

When I upload via Article > Image and Links > Full Article Image, it doesn't resize

I also have some media custom fields in the article, which it doesn't resize using those either.

Is there any way I can get the resize function to work via the Article Image upload and the Media custom field upload?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Are you actually uploading new files or selecting already uploaded images?

Comment: Uploading new images

Comment: I have also been able to resize images via Media and Articles. All methods I tried go to line #38 of `..\plugins\media-action\resize\resize.php` to do the resizing . There are a couple of conditions that silently return if not correct but otherwise there is not a lot of code really handling the resize. If you have a debug environment you might be able to narrow down your issue.